# Unlink clients state from servers state

Tags: ignite

I have 40 nodes server cluster and dozens of clients. When a client node restarts one of servers goes offline with logs about blocking system critical NIO worker, with next logs apppearing several times (3, probably because connection attempts configured to 3)

```
[09:02:27,567][SEVERE][sys-stripe-1-#2][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=ZookeeperClusterNode [id=5c10e43b-e726-4e5b-aa5c-2ccfc3e8abaa, addrs=[2001:558:0000:0000:250:56ff:fe9a:f36f%ens192, 2001:558:0000:0000:0:0:0:2f%ens192, 100.0.0.175, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1], order=297, loc=false, client=true], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtAtomicDeferredUpdateResponse [futIds=GridLongList [idx=5, arr=[6283512,6292346,6292347,6283518,6259652]]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node due to unrecoverable exception (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=5c10e43b-e726-4e5b-aa5c-2ccfc3e8abaa, addrs=[/[2001:558:0000:0000:250:56ff:fe9a:f36f%ens192]:47100, /[2001:558:0000:0000:0:0:0:2f%ens192]:47100, /100.0.0.175:47100, /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo]:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100], err= class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Remote node does not observe current node in topology : 5c10e43b-e726-4e5b-aa5c-2ccfc3e8abaa]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:625)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:693)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1181)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:691)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.createCommunicationClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:442)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.reserveClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:231)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1105)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1052)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2102)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2195)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1279)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1318)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.sendDeferredUpdateResponse(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:3510)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$2500(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:147)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$DeferredUpdateTimeout.run(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:3745)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.StripedExecutor$Stripe.body(StripedExecutor.java:637)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
        Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node due to unrecoverable exception (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=5c10e43b-e726-4e5b-aa5c-2ccfc3e8abaa, addrs=[/[2001:558:0000:0000:250:56ff:fe9a:f36f%ens192]:47100, /[2001:558:0000:0000:0:0:0:2f%ens192]:47100, /100.0.0.175:47100, /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo]:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100], err= class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Remote node does not observe current node in topology : 5c10e43b-e726-4e5b-aa5c-2ccfc3e8abaa]
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:627)
                ... 17 more
        Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Remote node does not observe current node in topology : 5c10e43b-e726-4e5b-aa5c-2ccfc3e8abaa
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:502)
                ... 17 more
        Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node due to unrecoverable exception (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=5c10e43b-e726-4e5b-aa5c-2ccfc3e8abaa, addrs=[/[2001:558:0000:0000:250:56ff:fe9a:f36f%ens192]:47100, /[2001:558:0000:0000:0:0:0:2f%ens192]:47100, /100.0.0.175:47100, /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo]:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100], err= class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Remote node does not observe current node in topology : 5c10e43b-e726-4e5b-aa5c-2ccfc3e8abaa]
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:627)
                ... 17 more
        Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Remote node does not observe current node in topology : 5c10e43b-e726-4e5b-aa5c-2ccfc3e8abaa
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:502)
                ... 17 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Remote node does not observe current node in topology : 5c10e43b-e726-4e5b-aa5c-2ccfc3e8abaa
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:502)
        ... 17 more
```

after that

```
[09:03:26,145][SEVERE][grid-timeout-worker-#22][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=sys-stripe-1, threadName=sys-stripe-1-#2, blockedFor=95s]
[09:03:26,146][SEVERE][grid-timeout-worker-#22][] Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=RestartProcessFailureHandler [super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet []]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=sys-stripe-1, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1697619710526]]]
```

it tried to di restart but in all cases not successfully.

Based on log it tries to keep connection with previous running client instance which is already restarted.

So shortly - server nodes may be affected by state of clients. Is there a way to comletely "unlink" states, so no matter what happens with clients server nodes will not be affected?

We can play with timeouts but this states "link" is still there. I saw something about server nodes sending some data to clients, is there a way to disable it? Is it some system critical data?
Are thin clients work differently?

Notes:
ZK discovery SPI is used

Tried to lower connection timeouts and increase systemWorkerBlockedTimeout, that still will not help if something critical happens in network and state of server is still may be affected by clients' state

Tried to set IGNITE_ENABLE_FORCIBLE_NODE_KILL to true, but that still not solves the problem with states relation

Comment: Can you share a larger log snippet? In general it shouldn't cause a server node to get down. How do you switch your clients off?

Comment: @VladimirPligin updated logs. in some cases client JVMs restart with OOMs. there's no connection closing code on client side. later added
`this.managedConnection.getConnection().close();` on clients but that still didn't help

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you trying to turn the clients off in non-graceful manner. It gives server nodes no choice but to detect that something went wrong. Try switching your client nodes gracefully. In general the way to go is to programmatically call `Ignite.close()`. Additional info can be found on the [page](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/starting-nodes#shutting-down-nodes).

Additional thoughts.

- I can see from the log snippets (`[super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet []]]`) that there's an empty list of ignored failure types. This must've been explicitly configured. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77013288/stopping-local-node-on-ignite-failure-v2-15-0/77023546#77023546) to an answer about this. Most likely `SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED` shouldn't be excluded from the list.
- In general a user should play around mostly with [failure detection timeout](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/clustering/network-configuration#connection-timeouts). Cases when a user needs to change `systemWorkerBlockedTimeout` or similar timeouts look pretty narrow and specific to me.
- In your case [thin](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/thin-clients/java-thin-client) clients may be the way to go, in case its functionality is enough. Thick clients are full-fledged participants of a cluster, it makes them more aware of (and dependent on) what's going on with servers and visa versa. On the contrary thin clients are much more lightweight.

Comment: Unfortunatelly 1 and 2 didn't help and using thin client is not an option - we need to invoke custom processors